# How to convert list into DataFrame in Python (Binance Futures API)

Tags: list, dataframe, binance

Using Binance Futures API I am trying to get a proper form of my position regarding cryptocurrencies.
Using the code

```
from binance_f import RequestClient
request_client = RequestClient(api_key= my_key, secret_key=my_secet_key)
result = request_client.get_position()
```

I get the following result

```
[{"symbol":"BTCUSDT","positionAmt":"0.000","entryPrice":"0.00000","markPrice":"5455.13008723","unRealizedProfit":"0.00000000","liquidationPrice":"0","leverage":"20","maxNotionalValue":"5000000","marginType":"cross","isolatedMargin":"0.00000000","isAutoAddMargin":"false"}]
```

The `type` command indicates it is a list, however adding at the end of the code `print(result)` yields:

```
[<binance_f.model.position.Position object at 0x1135cb670>]
```

Which is baffling because it seems not to be the list (in fact, debugging it indicates object of type Position). Using `PrintMix.print_data(result)` yields:

```
data number 0 :
entryPrice:0.0
isAutoAddMargin:True
isolatedMargin:0.0
json_parse:<function Position.json_parse at 0x1165af820>
leverage:20.0
liquidationPrice:0.0
marginType:cross
markPrice:5442.28502271
maxNotionalValue:5000000.0
positionAmt:0.0
symbol:BTCUSDT
unrealizedProfit:0.0
```

Now it seems like a JSON format... But it is a list. I am confused - any ideas how I can convert result to a proper DataFrame? So that columns are `Symbol, PositionAmt, entryPrice, etc.`

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "the `type` command"? any way you are getting a list with one object, the one that `PrintMix.print_data` is showing you...

Comment: print(type(result))

Comment: Ok, so see my comment above...

Comment: The question is how to convert it to DataFrame with columns being symbol, positionAmt and so on (as displayed by PrintMix)

Comment: The inner object is `dict` so you can just use `pandas.DateFrame.from_dict()`. Please read `pandas` decomentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) or [this article](https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-create-dataframe-from-dictionary/)

Comment: Tried it, but when trying to print the DataFrame the outcome still  "0  <binance_f.model.position.Position object at 0..."

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
print(df)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main question remains as you wrote on the header you should not be confused. In your case you have a list of `Position` object, you can see the structure of `Position` in the [GitHub of this library](https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/blob/master/binance_f/model/position.py)

Anyway to answer the question please use the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([t.__dict__ for t in result])
```

For more options and information please read the great answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997174/how-to-convert-list-of-model-objects-to-pandas-dataframe)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use that

```
df = pd.DataFrame([t.__dict__ for t in result])
klines=df.values.tolist()
open = [float(entry[1]) for entry in klines]
high = [float(entry[2]) for entry in klines]
low = [float(entry[3]) for entry in klines]                               
close = [float(entry[4]) for entry in klines]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?